# Can I bind multiple data object to same window but different tabs in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, data-binding

**XAML**

```
 <TabControl>
     <TabItem Header="Device" BorderBrush="#FF000209" Background="#FF000000" x:Name="Tab_STATUS">
       <Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"   Content="Device Name" Margin="14.439,24.192,-83.497,8"  d:IsStaticText="True" Background="#00D32626" x:Name="Label_DeviceName" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" />
       <Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"   Content="{Binding DEVICE_NAME, Mode = OneWay}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="31.844,24.192,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Label_DeviceName_Value" />
    </TabItem>


    <TabItem Header="User" BorderBrush="#FF000209" Background="#FF000000" x:Name="Tab_STATUS">
       <Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"   Content="User Name" Margin="14.439,24.192,-83.497,8"  d:IsStaticText="True" Background="#00D32626" x:Name="Label_UserName" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" />
       <Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"   Content="{Binding USERR_NAME, Mode = OneWay}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="31.844,24.192,0,8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Label_UserName_Value" />
    </TabItem>


 </TabControl>
```

Above `TabControl` has two `TabItem` named Device and User respectively.

**Device** Tab has to be binded with **DeviceInfo** and  **User** tab with **UserInfo**.

Below is the XAML.CS 
i am not able to bind both device and user at the same time.

**XAML.CS** : This Window Has Multiple Tabs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DeviceInfo Phone= new Phone{ DEVICE_NAME = "xxx", DEVICE_ID = "123456789",};
        User_info = new User_info ("ZZZZ", "18", "5.8", "65kg");
        this.DataContext = cpu_info; 
       //Unable to bind hence commented.
       // this.DataContext = User_info ;

    }
```

I am new to the data binding concepts,I am unable to understand the concept exactly.
If I have to bind different data to same window ? How do i do it?Please Help Me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your goal:

- Create a specific class that will contain the properties that you want to display, that is to say, a ViewModel (in the MVVM architecture), and let your DataContext be an instance of that class.
- Use the window itself as its own DataContext (not MVVM).

**Note**: The DataContext of a FrameworkElement is inherited from the parent by default.

1st solution :

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        User = new User_info("ZZZZ", "18", "5.8", "65kg");
        Phone = new Phone { DEVICE_NAME = "xxx", DEVICE_ID = "123456789" };
    }

    public User_info User { get; set; }

    public DeviceInfo Phone { get; set; }

    // If you need only the device's name in the view
    public string DeviceName => Phone.DEVICE_NAME;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml** (simplified)

```
<TabItem Header="User">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding User.USER_NAME}"/>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Device">
    <TexBlock Text="{Binding Phone.DEVICE_NAME}"/>
    <!-- OR -->
    <TexBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
</TabItem>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The second solution is to move the properties of MainWindowViewModel to the code-behind, and set `DataContext = this;` in the constructor.

Other thoughts:

- If the bound properties are not static and subject to change, your DataContext needs to notify the view, it will not be automatically updated. You need to Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or inherit a class that does it for you, such as `Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase`.
- When binding to a TextBlock or Label, you don't need to specify `Mode=OneWay`, unless you change the value from the code-behind.
- You should use a `TextBlock` if you don't need the `AccessText` feature of `Label`.

Comment: Currently i am working with the implementaion,as i am a begginer to this topic i am little slow in the understanding process. I Appreciate your support and help,once i clearly implement it i ll will respond to the post further. Thank You.

Comment: I Tried executing the following method,but i was not able to do so? No data is being displayed on the view.

Comment: Thank you ,i was doing it wrong,was able to figure my mistake .This one worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to set your Window's datacontext to `Self` and create two properties: `UserInfo` and `DeviceInfo` to which your tab items will be bound:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public DeviceInfo DeviceInfo { get; }

    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DeviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();
        UserInfo = new UserInfo();
    }
}
```

And in your xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        Title="MainWindow"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Device" DataContext="{Binding DeviceInfo}"/>
            <TabItem Header="User"  DataContext="{Binding UserInfo}"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have removed those parts of your code that are not relevant for answering the question.

Comment: Currently i am working with the implementaion,as i am a begginer to this topic i am little slow in the understanding process. I Appreciate your support and help,once i clearly implement it i ll will respond to the post further. Thank You.